# How to Convert AWS S3 bucket stream response into a file in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-s3, .net-core

I created a utility class for Amazon AWS S3 bucket related stuff so that I can reuse the utility in different controllers.

I am trying to get the file from S3 bucket I am able to fetch the file as a stream, now I want convert it into an original file, but when I am trying to return the `File`, I am getting an error

> Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method

Is there a way to convert stream into a file through a class not from the controller.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task GetFileFromBucket(string fileName)
{
      var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(_bucket, fileName);
      return File(response.ResponseStream, response.Headers["Content-Type"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to convert stream into a file through a class not from the Controller

The File Contents is either a string or a stream:

```
public async Task<string> GetFileFromBucket(string fileName)
{
      var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(_bucket, fileName);
      return new File(response.ResponseStream, response.Headers["Content-Type"]).ReadAllText();
}
```

If you want the S3 bucket or file meta data then call a different S3 API. I'm assuming you want the file contents.

Comment: Getting error saying cannot create a instance of static class 'File'